# How can I interact with R-Project on a LAMP system?

Tags: mysql, r, lamp

I've been looking around for a way to interact with R-project (http://www.r-project.org/) on a LAMP system. I don't need the plotting functionality. I am just looking for a way to run linear regression and correlation on a data set in .csv format (or from MySQL). I also need to pull or save the output coefficients.

Has anyone used or found a package that would be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out Rserve. It offers a php client to communicate with R. Rserve is a server that spawns processes that link to the R shared library and allow you to run scripts using a socket api.

http://rforge.net/Rserve/